# Question on product of primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How to prove the following result:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i=\frac{2^{(P_n+3)/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \gamma (1+P_n/2) \cdot \frac1R$$

where $R$ is the product the odd composite natural numbers less than $P_n$ and $n>2$.

Comment: What's $\gamma$?

Comment: Are you still here, Manjil? Do you have any thoughts on the answer I posted?

Comment: $\gamma$ is the Euler's function. Sorry I was off the loop for a while.

Comment: Welcome back. So: any thoughts on the two answers that have been posted?

Comment: This is the way I originally thought, but I don't know how does one get a formula involving $\pi$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: Well, $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$, so any formula with factorial in it can be rewritten with $\Gamma$ instead. $\sqrt\pi$ comes in when you evaluate $\Gamma$ at half-integers. Anyway, where exactly did you come across this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $R\prod_1^nP_i$ is just twice the product of all the odd numbers up to $P_n$, and that product of odd numbers is $(P_n+1)!$ divided by the product of the even numbers up to $P_n+1$, and that product in turn is $2^{(P_n+1)/2}$ times the factorial of $(P_n+1)/2$.

Comment: Having worked a lot recently with $(2n)!!$, this looks right (+1) Of course, it would be nice to know what $\gamma$ is.

Comment: @rob, I'm guessing it's the Gamma function. But only OP knows, and he/she is maintaining radio silence.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what $\gamma$ is, here is an asymptotic approximation:
$$
\begin{align}
R\prod_{i=1}^nP_i
&=P_n!!\\
&=\frac{(P_n+1)!}{2^{(P_n+1)/2}\left(\frac{P_n+1}{2}\right)!}\\
&\sim\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{P_n+1}{e}\right)^{\frac{P_i+1}{2}}
\end{align}
$$